# How can I switch peferred handling of attachment downloads in Outlook?

Tags: microsoft-outlook, attachments

Due to some recent update of Microsoft Outlook (used in Firefox, on Ubuntu 20) there is no more download dialog for attachments. (At least I guess this has changed recently.)

When I click on download, the file is opened in the Browser immediately, at least if it is a PDF file. It seems like the download actually does a preview.

[image: Download Button]

I want to be able to open the file in a different app or just store it on my disc, but these options are gone.

Here is the attachment preferences panel:
[image: Attachment Preferences (Outlook)]

Looking for help on [Microsoft's website](https://support.microsoft.com/search/results?query=preferences%20attachment%20downloads&isEnrichedQuery=false) did not bring up anything helpful.

Is there anything I can do in order to change this behavior?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It sounds like you want to change how Firefox handles PDF files.  If so...

1. Open Firefox
2. Open the hamburger menu and click on **Settings**
3. Click the **General** panel
4. Go down to **Applications** section
5. Find **Portable Document Format (PDF)** in the list and select it
6. Click the down arrow under **Action** column
7. Choose the option (eg, **Always ask**, or **Save File**) from the drop-down list.
8. Restart Firefox

For more info, [visit](https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/kb/view-pdf-files-firefox-or-choose-another-viewer#w_set-firefox-to-ask-you-what-to-do-with-pdf-files)

Comment: Yeah, it was a Firefox settings thing! Thanks so much!